# Single atom thruster

Tags: momentum, acceleration, atoms, space

Would it be possible to accelerate a single atom inside a space ship that, after exiting the ship's exhaust, it would take the ship from Earth orbit to Mars?

Comment: Theoretically you can accelerate a single particle to an arbitrarily large momentum/energy.  The ship will be accelerated in response to that.  So yes.  Sure.

Comment: Practically, however you would need a rather large accelerator to accelerate the ion to the velocity involved.....which would increase the inertia of the ship even more, so I think you would still find it impossible, as the more acceleration needed for the particle, the heavier the ship,  therefore...well you can see where this is going.

Answer (score 0):

You might produce a single impulse of acceleration, rather than sustained acceleration, so it's not the same idea as an ion thruster engine. The Deep Space 1 spacecraft, powered by an ion thruster, changed velocity by 4300 m/s while consuming less than 74 kilograms of xenon. This is equivalent to 131 moles of xenon, each mole having $6.022 × 10^{23}$ atoms,

So you would have one unmeasurably small impulse followed by constant velocity, **if** you ignore the inherent inertia produced by the mass of the ship. I doubt NASA will extend their Faster, Better, Cheaper mantra to this level.

It would not, in the real word, work as a propulsion system, as the acceleration produced by one atom or ion would not alter whatever inertia, linear, and angular motion the spaceship already has by any significant or even detectable amount.

As I say in the comments above, I would have to regretfully disagree with DilithiumMatrix,  as the more energy  you wanted to give that single ion, the  larger the accelerator needed, therefore the more massive the spaceship becomes, and this cycle continues indefinitely,  so you are fighting a losing battle. This means imo, that even in theory, the idea would not  work.